# Why is this method called without being asked to?

Tags: php, oop, methods

I came across this very strange behavior.
The following code

```
class TestClass {
    function testClass() {
        echo "Don't show me!";
    }
}

$testing = new TestClass;
```

executes its method `testClass` without it being called!
However, `testClass` won't run if renamed into anything else like `testClass1`.
Is there any hidden 'PHP magic' behind this behaviour?

EDIT.
At the end I see this question is trivial to ninjas grown up with PHP. As recent newcomer to PHP, I've learned to use `__construct` as constructor. With that "relic behaviour" carefully removed from modern tutorials. I am so glad people realized how terrible it was, changing class name and forgetting to change that of the constructor - what a nightmare!

Comment: A method with the name name as the class it is apart of will be considered the class constructor.

Comment: This method `testClass()` is named the same as the class itself. It will operate similar to a `__construct()` method. It is commonly better to use the `__construct()` though, as that is more clear to read.

Comment: If you don't want it called, add another method and name it __construct then the class will use __construct as the class constructor instead of the method with the same name as the class.

Comment: we rarely see good, minimal code examples like this one. I'm quite shocked :) upvoted.

Comment: Thanks, found the reference http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php, saying though "As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes." Rather confusing!

Comment: PHP is a very confusing language indeed.

Comment: I guess 'minimal code' is precisely the reason for the downvotes :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It is the sentence "the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name" that is confusing. The name is not the same - it is not capitalized.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: PHP is case insensitive.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath "The variable name is case-sensitive" according to [PHP Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: functions and methods aren't http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php  I told you it's confusing ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That sounds better :), thanks. It is not as simple as I've thought, here is a good reference: http://the-echoplex.net/log/php-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre-PHP5, the `__construct` method was not used as the class constructor.  Instead, a method with the same name as the class was used.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.decon.php):

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a `__construct()` function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics.

Creating a (empty) constructor (method named `__construct`) will stop the message from being echoed upon class initialization (only needed for < PHP 5.3.3 *):

```
class TestClass {
    function __construct() {

    }
    function testClass() {
        echo "Don't show me!";
    }
}
```

> *  [As of PHP 5.3.3](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.3), methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of PHP a method with the same name as the classname was considered the constructor.